# How to View Oracle Stored Procedure using SQLPlus?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g, sqlplus

How can I view the code of a stored procedure using sqlplus for Oracle 10g?

When I type in:

```
desc daily_update;
```

it shows me the parameter, but when I try to do the following:

```
select * from all_source where name = 'daily_update';
```

I get

> no rows selected

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

check your casing, the name is typically stored in upper case

> SELECT * 
>   FROM all_source 
>   WHERE name = 'DAILY_UPDATE' 
>   ORDER BY TYPE, LINE;

Comment: Just a heads up, you might want to `order by line`. By default, the lines are correctly ordered for me without the `order by` in some quick testing, so I'm not sure if it is necessary or not

Comment: IMHO `order by type` is useless since we already provided the name of the object

Comment: I actually put the ORDER BY TYPE (etc) there in case someone took the example and modified the WHERE clause (perhaps changing the = to a like etc); but you are correct, as an example I wanted it to work forward.  I tend to like to always specify an ORDER BY in case things in the optimizer change in the future my queries will continue to operate as normal

Comment: The ORDER BY TYPE Is relevant when displaying package code, as you want the package declaration to be listed before the package body.