# How to find Lines of Code of packaged procedures and functions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, package, lines-of-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to View Oracle Stored Procedure using SQLPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000224/how-to-view-oracle-stored-procedure-using-sqlplus)

Im new to Oracle. Could you please help me on this?

How to fine Lines of Code of packaged procedures and functions in Oracle?

Is there any system tables or query to find the LOC of procedures and functions inside any package?

Comment: This is not a duplicate just because it has the same answer *facepalm*

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [ALL_SOURCE view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2063.htm) in the Oracle dictionary.